# Automatically adding \noindent after \section{*}

Tags: sectioning, indentation, titlesec, abnt

I'm using `titlesec` package and a document class [ABNT Class](http://codigolivre.org.br/frs/download.php/2654/abntex-0.8-2.tgz) which follows a Brazilian standard for document development. So far I've managed to follow the Brazilian Computer Association guidelines for making a scientific article (which is my real objective, for further reuse), however using both the `abnt` class and the `titlesec` package breaks document indentation, as each paragraph had a fixed indentation which `titlesec` could not manage, adding `[noindentafter]{titlesec}` produces no results, so I've decided to force document's whole indentation by using `setspace` and using the following code

```
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
```

To prevent first paragraph's indentation (which is required by this scientific article model), I've to use `\noindent` after `\section{}`, `\subsection{}` and `\subsubsection` which is really annoying, is there any way to automatically embed `\noindent` to the end of the section function call? this would be as simple as `\section{*}\noindent`

*Edit*: I'm providing a MWS for further checking

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{abnt}

\usepackage{setspace,titlesec,setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{13.5pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.75cm}{}[]
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document} 
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
This first paragraph is indented, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. 

This paragraph is also indented, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in
sapien. 

\section{Pellentesque Placerat}\noindent
This first paragraph is using noindented, praesent in
sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 

This paragraph is indented, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in
sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.
Sed interdum libero ut metus. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\titlespacing*{\section}{left margin space}{vertical space before}{vertical space after}`? According to the manual this kills the indentation after the sectioning unit.

Comment: I'm currently using `\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}` but like I said before, the whole document indentation was broken, and using this has no result as well (the expected result), if there is any way to embed `\noindent` this serves me well.
I think that `\titlespacing` works on title and not exactly after it, I need a text which is non indented in the first paragraph, moreover the subsequent paragraphs doesn't follow this rule

at first glance I thought of `\titleformat{\section}{}{}{}{}[insertingindentationhere]` however it does not produce the result I need

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) The standard LaTeX approach automatically adds `\noindent` after sections. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Perhaps the `abnt` package requires the babel package with brazilian/portuguese option?. I recall having similar indentation problems using the babel package with the spanish option.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39232/15647), it may help.

Comment: looking at abnt.cls (not on ctan, but easily enough found by a google grope), i see no particular reason that this should be happening (note, this is from reading the code -- i don't even speak portuguese, let alone the brazilian version, to read docs).  we really need that min example...

Comment: The standard section commands all automatically suppress indentation before the first paragraph (note they do _not_ do it by inserting `\noindent` which would mess up vertical spacing, and interfere with the prevention of a page break after the heading. Thus we need a minimal example to see why this is not happening in your case.

Comment: Also If titlesec is using the standard latex `\@startsection` then it is best _not_ to use `0pt` lengths, Standard latex sectioning uses the sign of the length as a switch to suppress or allow indentation but 0 of course doesn't really have a sign so it depends on the details of the exact test used. Better to use small positive (or negative) values.

Comment: [Minimal Working Example](http://i.imgur.com/hAE9c.png)

Comment: @RicardoBarrosDuarte: No, you should post *code* that reflects the output you posted as an image. That way every member of the community can take that code, compile it locally, and figure out what's going on. That makes your problem universally negotiable.

Comment: I've edited the question providing the MWE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's quite strange that the model requires both ABNT and no indentation after a section title.

`setspace` and `titlesec` are not needed. Rather you have to revert the modification made by `indentfirst`, which is loaded by `abnt.cls`. The following  document shows how:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{abnt}

\makeatletter
% package indentfirst says \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
% and we revert this modification, reinstating the original definitio
% of \@afterindentfalse
\def\@afterindentfalse{\let\if@afterindent\iffalse}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
This first paragraph is \emph{NOT} indented, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.

This paragraph is indented, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. 
Praesent in sapien.

\section*{Pellentesque Placerat}
This first paragraph is \emph{NOT} indented, praesent in
sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

This paragraph is indented, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. 
Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing 
elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.

\end{document}
```