# Getting the page breaks right for a \beginsection macro

Tags: sectioning, tex-core, plain-tex

I've found this code in the question [No indent in the first paragraph in a section in Plain TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85819/no-indent-in-the-first-paragraph-in-a-section-in-plain-tex/85820#85820)

```
\def\mysection#1{%
  \goodbreak
  \vskip2\baselineskip
  \noindent #1\par
  \nobreak
  \vskip\baselineskip
  \everypar={{\setbox0\lastbox}\everypar={}}}
```

but it doesn't stretch the bottom of the page when the page breaks on a new paragraph (here the stretching was found in the skips around the section title).

[image: The skips around the title are stretched when the page breaks around a \mysection]

So I tried

```
\def\mysection#1{%
  \filbreak
  \vskip2\baselineskip
  \noindent #1\par
  \nobreak
  \vskip\baselineskip
  \everypar={{\setbox0\lastbox}\everypar={}}}
```

which now encourages page breaks a bit too much... (The 2nd page was broken before the 3d section)
[image: with \filbreak, the page breaks too easily around a \mysection]

Here is my question: how can I define a `\mysection` that

- breaks the page if (and only if) there is no space for the section title and the first line of the first paragraph of the section;
- ends the page with a `\hfil` if the page is broken on a section title?

Test file:

```
\def\mysection#1{%
    \filbreak
    %\goodbreak
    \vskip2\baselineskip
    \noindent #1\par
    \nobreak
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \everypar={{\setbox0\lastbox}\everypar={}}}

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\mysection{Hello world!}
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\mysection{Nice title!}
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\mysection{This one too}
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
\bye
```

Comment: Use `\filbreak` instead of `\goodbreak`?

Comment: @egreg It's a good start but it has some bugs (I reformulated the question)

Answer (score 5):

Use the same idea as `\filbreak`, but with a finite `plus` component:

```
\def\mysection#1{%
    \par
    \vskip2\baselineskip plus 3\baselineskip
    \penalty-500
    \vskip 0pt plus -3\baselineskip
    \noindent #1\par
    \nobreak
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \everypar={{\setbox0\lastbox}\everypar={}}}

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\mysection{Hello world!}
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\mysection{Nice title!}
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\mysection{This one too}
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\bye
```

[image]

What's the idea of `\filbreak`? The command issues two `\vskip` commands with a `\penalty` in between:

```
\vskip<specs-a>
\penalty<amount>
\vskip<specs-b>
```

There are three cases:

1. No page break is taken at those items
2. A page break is taken at the first glue
3. A page break is taken at the penalty

Notice that the second glue is not a feasible page break point, because it's preceded by a penalty, which is a discardable item.

In case 1 the two glues will appear on the page; in case 2 the three items will disappear at the page break; in case 3 the second glue item will disappear.

Now, what does `\filbreak` do? Its definition is

```
\par\vfil\penalty-200\vfilneg
```

where `\vfil` and `\vfilneg` are primitives equivalent to

```
\vskip 0pt plus 1fil
```

and

```
\vskip 0pt plus -1fil
```

respectively. So, in case 1, no vertical space will result, because the infinite components cancel each other. In case 2, nothing will be “seen”. In case 3 only the `plus 1fil` will act, adding infinite stretchability to the page.

In my variation I use the same penalty as `\goodbreak` (-500), but the first glue item is `2\baselineskip plus 3\baselineskip` and the second glue item is `0pt plus -3\baselineskip`. The idea is the same: in case 1 the net amount of glue is `2\baselineskip`; in case 2 nothing is seen; in case 3 the amount of stretching is `3\baselineskip`, so TeX will be invited not to leave more space than needed for accommodating three lines: the section title, the empty line after it and the first line of the following paragraph. I'd try with two lines, to be honest, in order to avoid a club line.

Comment: Can you explain how and why it works? When I do `\vskip2\baselineskip plus \vsize
    \penalty-500
    \vskip 0pt plus -\vsize` I have the same problem of breaking the 2nd page in the middle.  Does it have to do with the fact that `3\baselineskip` is the size of "the title + the following white space + the first line of the next paragraph"?

Comment: @lvaneesbeeck With `plus \vsize` is just the same as `plus 1fil`, isn't it? With `plus 3\baselineskip` you add a finite amount of stretchability, so TeX won't be keen into leaving too much text in the next page.

Comment: \the\vsize prints 643.20255pt. If I change plus 3\baselineskip with 100\baselineskip I also have the same problem.

Comment: @lvaneesbeeck Of course. What did you expect?

Comment: well you said "let's add a finite stretchability". Okay so if I change the spacing after the title (e.g. for a subsection) the plus component has to be changed accordingly. I was thinking maybe there would be a "clean" way of doing.

I don't think it's strictly necessary to add space for the two first lines of the 1st paragraph since TeX will add a `\clubpenalty`. But it's safer anyway

Comment: I still don't get why adding too much stretchability breaks pages even when there is space for the section title. Does TeX first try to add skip of the natural with + the natural stretch before analyzing what comes next?

Comment: @lvaneesbeeck No, it doesn't, but makes more desirable to push contents in the next page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12157/discussion-between-lvaneesbeeck-and-egreg)