# Restore noindentafter functionality with polyglossia

Tags: indentation, polyglossia

When `polyglossia` is loaded `noindentafter` stops working:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
        \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
        \setmainlanguage{french}
        %   \PolyglossiaSetup{french}{indentfirst=false}
    \usepackage{noindentafter}
        \NoIndentAfterEnv{myitemize}

    \newenvironment{myitemize}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
   \begin{myitemize}
       \item test
   \end{myitemize}

   \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

This happens with all the languages I tested. In [No indent in the first paragraph in a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39227/no-indent-in-the-first-paragraph-in-a-section) egreg suggested to add `indentfirst=false` (commented in the code) but unfortunately it does not work for custom environments.

Is there a (possibly easy) way to restore the `noindentafter` functionality when using`polyglossia`?

Comment: why noindentafter{myitemize} rather than the standard latex markup which is not to indent after a list if there is no new paragraph?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need this for many different kinds of custom environments: tcolorboxes, tikzpictures, etc.

Comment: sure but a blank line meaning start of paragraph is deeply ingrained in latex and latex goes to lots of trouble to make that work even after a list. If you don't want to start a new paragraph, just don't insert a blank line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But this does not work with tcolorboxes? I still get indented text. E.g. try: `\begin{tcolorbox}test\end{tcolorbox}\lipsum`

Comment: a display environment based on colorbox should be using a trivlist environment (like center and quote verbatim and ...)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as far as I understand default tcolorboxes have a `\par` at the end.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this also does not work if you have a minipage of, say, 3cm. The text will go to the side of the minipage if you don't start a new paragraph.

Comment: a minipage is a horizontal mode construct, it is positioned like  a letter, if you are defining a vertical mode display environment you should use the in built constructs for that (which is the list environment, basically) the main reason the center and similar environments use a list is to handle indents  following the environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see your point, but since I'm using tcolorboxes a lot, which have that `\par` by default at the end, and since I might be using something else in a unorthodox way, I find convenient to add stuff to `\NoIndentAfterEnv` and live happily after. Consider also that in this specific use case I'm porting an already written document to LuaLaTeX, so the damage is already done :)

Comment: that's OK Andrew's got the tick anyway:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both packages are messing with `\@afterindentfalse`.  Fortunately `polyglossia` stores the old version `\@@fterindentfalse` so we can just redefine the central command `\NoIndentAfterThis` to use the stored version.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage{noindentafter}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\NoIndentAfterThis}{\par\@@fterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\NoIndentAfterEnv{myitemize}
\newenvironment{myitemize}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
Text. \NoIndentAfterThis Text.
\begin{myitemize}
\item test
\end{myitemize}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```