# How to set a 5 spaces indentation from the left for all paragraphs in LyX?

Tags: lyx, indentation, paragraphs

In each chapter now the first paragraph is not indented. But, to get all paragraphs to be equally indented I need some steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To indent the first paragraph after every section unit, follow the instructions in [No indent in the first paragraph in a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39227/5764) That is, load the [`indentfirst` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/indentfirst) as part of your preamble.

For a specific 5-space indentation, also add `\settowidth{\parindent}{~~~~~}` to the preamble. This adjust the width of `\parindent` - the measure by which paragraphs are indented to the width of 5 non-breaking spaces.

[image]

Note though that the presentation (in my opinion) may seem awkward:

[image]

Comment: Would this change impact any other existing format?

Comment: @kuru: It shouldn't, but I wouldn't know what else you might be doing with your document without more details...