# How to indent first paragraph after \section using Texstudio?

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I am using Texstudio to compose my assignment. However, I have a problem with it. After I used `\section*{}`, and the my first paragraph in section is indented to the very left. I want the paragraph starts with two space. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [No indent in the first paragraph in a section?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39227/5764)

Answer (score 3):

Package `indentfirst` enables the paragraph indentation after section titles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]