# No indentation of first line in amsbook chapter

Tags: indentation, amsbook

How do I have to change `amsbook.cls` such that the first line of a new chapter is not indented?

Comment: Related: [No indent in the first paragraph in a section?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39227/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first indent after chapters and sections is controlled by `\if@afterindent`. Class `amsbook` sets it to true. The following
example prevents this setting in the same way as package `indentfirst` does the opposite:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\let\@afterindenttrue\@afterindentfalse
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]