# Make amsart section titles in article document class

Tags: titlesec, article, amsart

I like the section titles in the `amsart` document class.

Is it possible to have a standard article, but the section titles from the amsart document class?

I have looked at `titlesec` package, but I do not know how to find the style of the section titles from the `amsart` document class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `titlesec` package. Add the following lines to your preamble to mimic the section headings of the `amsart` class.

```
\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section}{}{\thetitle.}{0.8em}{\centering\scshape}
\titleformat{name=\subsection}[runin]{}{\thetitle.}{0.5em}{\bfseries}[.]
\titleformat{name=\subsubsection}[runin]{}{\thetitle.}{0.5em}{\itshape}[.]
\titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[runin]{}{}{0em}{}[.]
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0em}{0em}{0.5em}
\titleformat{name=\subparagraph,numberless}[runin]{}{}{0em}{}[.]
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{0em}{0em}{0.5em}
```

As a comparison, here is a sample document typeset with the `article` class and the `titlesec` package on the one hand and with the `amsart` class on the other one.

[image]
[image]

The code for the document with `article`+`titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section}{}{\thetitle.}{0.8em}{\centering\scshape}
\titleformat{name=\subsection}[runin]{}{\thetitle.}{0.5em}{\bfseries}[.]
\titleformat{name=\subsubsection}[runin]{}{\thetitle.}{0.5em}{\itshape}[.]
\titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[runin]{}{}{0em}{}[.]
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0em}{0em}{0.5em}
\titleformat{name=\subparagraph,numberless}[runin]{}{}{0em}{}[.]
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{0em}{0em}{0.5em}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section{First section (article with titlesec)}
\blindtext
\subsection{First subsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\blindtext
\paragraph{First paragraph}
\blindtext
\subparagraph{First subparagraph}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The code for the `amsart` class:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section{First section (amsart)}
\blindtext
\subsection{First subsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\blindtext
\paragraph{First paragraph}
\blindtext
\subparagraph{First subparagraph}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: And subsubsections are just like subsections except the font is `\itshape`. Also `paragraph` and `subparagraph` are by default not numbered and the font is just `\normalfont`.

Comment: @Dan Thanks. I have now also added the definitions of the other section commands.

Answer (score 0):

Specific for `\section`s, you can use the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty,indentfirst}
\sectionfont{\normalfont\centering\scshape\normalsize}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Elaboration:

- [`indentfirst`](http://ctan.org/pkg/indentfirst) mimics [`amsart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart)'s "after section indentation". See [No indent in the first paragraph in a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39227/5764)
- [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) formats the header to the required font.
- Updating `\@seccntformat` appends a period after the section number.