# Simplest way to color section names in amsart

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I would like the font of the title of every section (and subsection) to be colored (say, blue, but ideally want to be able to use colors from the xcolor package). I am using the amsart document class and I do not want to make any other changes to the standard section format of the amsart class. The issue with solutions using the titlesec package, such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342923/make-amsart-section-titles-in-article-document-class), is that for whatever reason they seem to mess with the table of contents in the following two ways: 1) the listing of "References" disappears from the table of contents, and 2) the titles of the sections in the table of contents are printing over the section number sometimes (not sure why this happens).

Please let me know if there is a simple solution that I am missing.

Comment: Do you want to colour only  the section and subsection titles, aor also the (sub)section numbers?

Comment: Ideally both, but at least the titles.