# First line after new section or subsection is indented left

Tags: math-mode, sectioning

I'm brand new to latex and I'm using it to type up my physics homework, so it's almost all equations. I'm using a section for each problem and a subsection for each subproblem.

The first line when I open a new section, is indented more to the left than the following lines. I would prefer all the lines to be indented at the same level. Any advice?

Here is how I do the beginning of a new problem:

```
\section*{Problem 4}

Let $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ be vectors corresponding to the three sides of a triangle.
Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be the angles opposed those sides.
```

Here is my header:

```
\documentclass[16p, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{parskip}`

Comment: Perhaps you need [No indent in the first paragraph in a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39227/5764) Otherwise you may have to `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`.

Comment: `\documentclass[16p, oneside]{article}` cannot work ... correct is `\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}`

Comment: The \section macro ends with \@afterheading which prevents the first line from being indented.  If you are in an indented environment, this could have odd effects.