# Getting rid of indentation of first paragraph in AMS classes

Tags: indentation, amsart, amsbook

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Then a partial output is given by

[image]

Thus the AMS class automatically indents the first line of a paragraph after a section (or more generally, after a heading). However, as far as I read, the standard convention is to not indent the first line of a paragraph after a heading. How can I achieve this in this specific class? Moreover, why is this default in the AMS class?

Comment: Do you mean the first line of any paragraph or only the first line of the first paragraph after a heading? It is not at all unusual that the first lines of subsequent paragraphs are indented, but for the first paragraph you can either add the indentation or drop it. Both conventions are in use. I'd have thought that would be a matter of style and taste.

Comment: @moewe Sorry, added a clarification. I mean, I would like to not indent the first line after a heading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Borrowing from the excellent [`indentfirst`](https://ctan.org/pkg/indentfirst) but reversing the logic, you can try

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\@afterindenttrue\@afterindentfalse
\@afterindentfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

There seems to be no consensus on whether or not the first paragraph after a heading should start indented or not, see [No indent in the first paragraph in a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39227/35864), https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/3152 or https://practicaltypography.com/first-line-indents.html:

> A first-line indent on the first paragraph of any text is optional, because it’s obvious where the paragraph starts.

I guess you could argue for both sides. But it does not seem to be an issue that sparks a lot of controversies.

The LaTeX standard classes don't start the first paragraph indented, but `indentfirst` enables this behaviour for people who want this. Apparently someone thought that feature was worth the ordeal of writing a package for it. Apparently the AMS agrees and also indents the first paragraph.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek If you want to know why the AMS start with a paragraph indent, you try and can ask [barbara beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton), perhaps she happens to know who decided this.

Comment: +1 for the first 5 words:-)

Answer (score 2):

You can patch `\chapter` to issue `\@afterindentfalse` instead of `\@afterindenttrue`.

Also `\section` should be patched so its fourth argument has a negative value instead of positive.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\@afterindenttrue}{\@afterindentfalse}{}{}
\patchcmd{\section}
  {.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}
  {-.7\linespacing\@plus-\linespacing}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Test}

\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Test}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]