# No indent on first paragraph of a section with KOMA script

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, indentation, paragraphs

I am trying to reproduce the behavior described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39227/no-indent-in-the-first-paragraph-in-a-section) in a `scrartcl` document class using KOMA script.

My understanding is this is the default behavior for the `article` document class. However, KOMA script's default setting forces an indent on all paragraphs, including the first paragraph of a new section.

Comment: KOMA-Script does **not** force the indentation of the first paragraph after a section heading.. Did you change `beforeskip` for sections to a positive value?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suppression of the indentation of the paragraph following
the heading is the default behaviour of the KOMA-Script classes, too.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Bar}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

`scrartcl` declares `section` with the following code:

```latex
\DeclareSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  level=1,%
  indent=\z@,%
  beforeskip=-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex,%
  afterskip=2.3ex \@plus.2ex,%
  tocstyle=section,%
  tocindent=0pt,%
  tocnumwidth=1.5em%
]{section}
```

Note, `afterindent` is not set explicitely. So the default `afterindent=bysign` is active and the negative sign of `beforeskip` supresses the indentation of the first paragraph following the heading. The vertical skip before the heading is still positive.

If you want to change the value of `beforeskip`, you have to use the minus sign for its length , eg

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-10ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex
]{section}
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Bar}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can use a positive value for `beforeskip` and change `afterindent` to `false`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=10ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
  afterindent=false
]{section}
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Bar}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Both results in

[image]

---

**Warning:** If you only change `afterindent` to `true` or `false` without changing `beforeskip` to a positive value, the `section` heading could overlap the text before it:

[image]

Code:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterindent=false
]{section}
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Bar}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It didn't take me long to find the answer: Setting `afterindent=false` in `\RedeclareSectionCommand` does the trick.

Comment: If you set `afterindent=false`without changing `beforeskip` to a positive value, the heading could overlap the text before it.